# Website DNS issue from my machine only

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting

I've created a new website on m6.net hosting using fasthosts in the UK. When I try and load the website from my laptop I get a fasthosts landing page.

If I access the website from another machine it seems to work fine - http://www.validdomainauctions.com.

This would suggest it's not an issue with hosting, but I'm not sure why the domain redirects to a page on domain-holding.co.uk which states the following:

> This "website holding" page is displayed when you visit
>   validdomainauctions.com because the owner has registered the domain
>   name (or set up a sub-domain), but has not yet created a website.
>
> Without this page, website visitors would see a "Page not found"
>   error. The holding page confirms that the domain's DNS has been set up
>   correctly.

I've tried loading the website with Chrome, IE, and Mozilla, and the issue is the same with all of them, so it can't be the browser. I've tried clearing cache etc and that hasn't resolved anything.

I've called **ipconfig /flushdns** which hasn't helped either.

Comment: Did you try to execute an ipconfig /release then ipconfig /renew ?

Comment: I have now, but I'm still getting the issue.

Comment: Maybe your router is caching the dns table. Do you have any dns server on your network ? like an windows server acting as a dns server ? I've seen this happening when the dns server from network cached the table, so to solve it I've just reboot the dns service.

Comment: Interesting thought as I'm using the laptop at work. However I've tried taking the laptop home and using it over broadband but I still have the same issue. It works on other work machines, so the issue seems localized to only my machine. Strange.

Comment: Very strange it seens that something in your laptop is caching the dns. Maybe there is some static entry in windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts can you open that with notepad and look at ?

Comment: Yep, tried that and nothing. I wonder if Fasthosts is blocking a specific IP, but is that possible when I can access the site from other computers at work?

Comment: I dont think so, because if they are blocking then all computers would have this same problem as all users share the same IP.

Comment: Strange, I have another website which I've moved to a new hosting provider. I've updated the nameservers and the website works from other machines, but on my laptop it's still showing the old one. I've cleared the cache, flushed the DNS, etc etc. It's not a cache issue as I can load pages of the website I haven't loaded before from the machine, so it's still pointing to the old IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of being utterly baffled it would seem the issue has rectified itself. Happy days.